# How to implement error handler while using Jackson library

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, jackson, objectmapper

I am using jackson library to read json file as below.

```
        final byte[] jsonData = Files
                .readAllBytes(Paths.get("filePath"));

        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final InputFileBO myMap = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, InputFileBO.class);
```

The json format is,

```
{
    "header": {
        "type": "items",
        "date": "2019-07-16",
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "requestId": "123",
            "recSeq": 01,
        },

        {
            "requestId": "123",
            "recSeq": 1,
        }
    ]
}
```

Here for numeric fields leading zero's should not be allowed so the first record alone should fail and second one should process.

But the whole file fails while de-serialization.

Is it possible to get valid item's alone to "myMap".

Can someone please suggest how to achieve this.